# In TensorFlow, how do I know which rows are indexed?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here, I have an index matrix `index`, which is indexes of an array `a`. The tensors are as below.

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

index = tf.constant([
            [ 1, 2, 3,-1,-1],
            [ 6, 1, 3,-1,-1],
            [ 1, 3,-1, 5, 6],
            [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
            [ 6,-1, 9,-1,-1]
        ])

a = tf.constant([0,0,0,0,
                 0,0,0,0,
                 0,0,0,0,
                 0,0,0,0,], dtype=np.int32)
```

I want to get an array `indexed` which indicates those have been indexed by `index` as below.

```python
indexed = [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
#           0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

I know `tf.scatter_nd_update` or `tf.scatter_update` may be helpful. But, I don't know how to deal with `-1`, which represents an invalid index (just for padding the length). So, how do I get the `indexed` array as above ?

Comment: How is `index` related to `a` and `indexed`?

Comment: the number in `index` means where should be `1` in `indexed`. The `a` is given to give the length of `indexed`.

Comment: But `index` and `a` have different number of elements?

Comment: Yes. Some of the elements of `a` may be indexed multitimes and some may be not indexed.  The demension of `index` has nothing to do with `indexed` and it may be flatten into a one-demension array as long as the numbers in `index` keep the same, the result `indexed` should be the same.